# How to obtain a pdf document for use in another Laravel method - PDF

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the package [ESC/POS Print](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php), , what I try is to print the pdf generated with the package [laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) but I can not make it work, this is the error that shows me

> "message": "ImagickException: UnableToOpenBlob
>   '/storage/app/public/27.pdf'

this is my code, adapted from an [example](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php/blob/development/example/print-from-pdf.php) on github

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('miView', compact('data'))
    ->setPaper([0, 0, 420.78, 270.94], 'landscape');
Storage::disk('public')->put($id.'.pdf',$pdf->output());
$pdf = '/storage/app/public/'.$id.'.pdf';
$connector = new NetworkPrintConnector("x.x.x.x", 9100);
$printer = new Printer($connector);
try {
    $pages = ImagickEscposImage::loadPdf($pdf);
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $printer->graphics($page);
    }
    $printer -> cut();
    $printer -> close();
} finally {
    $printer -> close();
}
```

The configuration for public is as follows in filesystems.php

```
 'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Comment: Try using `Storage::disk('local')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix() . '/app/public/' . $id . '.pdf'` to ensure you're getting the full path to the file.

Comment: create a path and with that code otengo `C:\laragon\www\pos\storage\app/public\/app/public/2.pdf` , I'm using as public disk, I modified to `Storage::disk('public')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix() . '2.pdf';`  but I get error **ImagickException: PDFDelegateFailed `The system can not find the specified file**

Comment: Sorry my bad! Try the following instead: `Storage::disk('public')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix() . '\' . $id . '.pdf'`. Didn't know you were on Windows.

Comment: I keep getting the same error  ImagickException: PDFDelegateFailed `The system can not find the specified file